# constant value decay resulting in the same downward slope

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, plot

I need to decay, or steadily decrease values over time, resulting in the **same downward slope** for all values.  The values can be positive or negative, and range from small `± .01` to large `± 100.0`.

In my code, I set up a `linear_decay` array, in which I attempt to decay values by multiplication.  Unfortunately this leads to scaling issues - where large numbers have a steeper slope downwards than smaller values.  I need all the slopes to be the same, ideally at a -45° angle, or in terms of the equation of a line `y = mx+b`, `m = -1`.

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# timeseries will be 10 units long
points = 10

# create an array that will decay the values over time
linear_decay = np.linspace(0, 1, points, endpoint=False)[::-1]
```

Printing out `linear_decay`, you see that is looks like:

`[0.9 0.8 0.7 0.6 0.5 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.1 0. ]`

Now I create some data - arrays full of the same exact value so I can see how they decay over time.

```
x = np.arange(points)
y = np.full((points,), 1)  # an array full of 1s
y_25 = y * 25
y_75 = y * 75
y_neg_25 = y * -25
y_neg_75 = y * -75
```

Simply multiplying by `linear_decay` does not work for the negative values, and everything converges to zero, which I do not want:

```
plt.plot(
    x, y_25 * linear_decay,
    x, y_75 * linear_decay,
    x, y_neg_25 * linear_decay,
    x, y_neg_75 * linear_decay,
);
```

[image: multiplication method]

I can correct for the negative values, but I cannot figure out how to scale the same across both small and large values to get the same slope.  Here is closest I've gotten so far:

```
plt.plot(
    x, y_25 - abs(y_25 - (linear_decay * y_25)),
    x, y_75 - abs(y_75 - (linear_decay * y_75)),
    x, y_neg_25 - abs(y_neg_25 - (linear_decay * y_neg_25)),
    x, y_neg_75 - abs(y_neg_75 - (linear_decay * y_neg_75))
);
```

[image: slopes are all wrong]

You can see that the larger numbers results in steeper slopes, and the smaller numbers look flat.  I can't figure out how to get the same slope for all values.

Comment: Don't multiply the array `linear_decay` by a constant.  Instead, add a constant to shift the array up or down.  E.g. `linear_decay + 1`, `linear_decay - 25`, etc.

Comment: you are correct.  I am way overthinking this.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to simply subtract a constant value.

```
sub_array = np.linspace(points, 1, 10)[::-1]
plt.plot(
    x, y_25 - sub_array,
    x, y_75 - sub_array,
    x, y_neg_25 - sub_array,
    x, y_neg_75 - sub_array
);
```

[image]